# Sum and integral. Swap?

Tags: integration, summation, solution-verification

I have that
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{1}{1+n^2}\right)e^{inx}\right)\text{.}$$
Then I have to find $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Wolfram Alpha give me
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{inx}}{1+n^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2\sin(\pi n)}{n^3+n}\text{.}$$
And if I take the sum of it I get:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2\sin(\pi n)}{n^3+n}=2\pi\text{.}$$
So $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\,\mathrm{d}x=2\pi$. Is that correct? I think I can swap the sum and integral? If it is correct how can I formally show it?

Comment: Swapping is justified by uniform convergence.Your answer is correct but you have $\frac 0 0$ in your sum. If you keep the term corresponding to $n=0$ separately everything would be fine.

Comment: Formatting note: \$\$ gives you \displaystyle by default, you don't have to specify it again. Functions like \sin can be made commands to look better, and I personally use \,\mathrm{d}x for infinitesimals.